# Add a click event to a javafx object to run a function outside the class

Tags: java, javafx, state, state-machine

So I'm trying to get a state machine working - where different states cause different scenes to render - and clicking on objects in these scenes changes the scene.

Here's part of the state machine:

```
AnimationTimer animator = new AnimationTimer() {

            public void handle(long now) {

                switch (currentState) {
                case TOWN:
                    //Update
                    //Render
                    Town.showTownUI(stage);
                    break;
                case FOREST:
                    //Update
                    //Render
                    Forest.showForestUI(stage);
                    break;
                default:
                    //Update
                    //Render
                    break;
                }

            }
}
```

And I have a function in the main class to change state:

```
public void changeState(State State) {
    this.currentState = State;
}
```

And as an example, here is the Forest Class.

```
public class Forest {
    Group forestGroup = new Group();
    Scene forest;

    public void makeUI(Stage stage) {

        // Test Circle
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setCenterX(100);
        circle.setCenterY(200);
        circle.setRadius(40);
        circle.setFill(Color.RED);

        forestGroup.getChildren().addAll(circle);
        forest = new Scene(forestGroup, 600, 500);

    }

    public void showForestUI(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(forest);
    }

}
```

The trouble I'm having is trying to apply an event onto 'circle' to call the changeState function - because it's not in the same class where makeUI is defined. Is there a way to bind or delegate events in this way?

Comment: All you need to do is to pass a reference to your "main class" instance to the object that has a reference to the circle, and then call `main.changeState(...)`. It is not at all clear why you're using an `AnimationTimer` here. You will end up calling one of the `showXXXUI(...)` methods on every single rendering of the frame, which is excessive (to say the least).

Comment: @James_D - Thanks for the comment - any suggestions on how I can call the showUI() methods a single time?

Comment: If you make `currentState` a [JavaFX property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107), you can register a listener with it and call the appropriate `showUI()` method only when it changes.